# const T* const point to Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

```
struct AscendReprojectionError {
    AscendReprojectionError(double observed_x, double observed_y)
        : observed_x(observed_x), observed_y(observed_y) {}

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* const camera,
        const T* const point,
        T* residuals) const {       

        Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> rot = Eigen::Map <Eigen::Matrix< T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> >(camera);

        return true;
    }

    // Factory to hide the construction of the CostFunction object from
    // the client code.
    static ceres::CostFunction* Create(const double observed_x,
        const double observed_y) {
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<AscendReprojectionError, 2, 9, 3>(
            new AscendReprojectionError(observed_x, observed_y)));
    }

    double observed_x;
    double observed_y;
};
```

How do I defined the Eigen Matrix that contains the 9 points in const T* const point? The above was my failed attempt

```
Error   3   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const JetT *const ' to 'Eigen::Map<Derived,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>'   C:\dev\ceres-solver-1.8.0\examples\simple_bundle_adjuster.cc    133 1   simple_bundle_adjuster
Error   2   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const double *const ' to 'Eigen::Map<Derived,0,Eigen::Stride<0,0>>' C:\dev\ceres-solver-1.8.0\examples\simple_bundle_adjuster.cc    133 1   simple_bundle_adjuster
```

Question in comments:

```
class CostFunction {
 public:
  CostFunction() : num_residuals_(0) {}

  virtual ~CostFunction() {}
```

After adding the rest of the code again.

the following error is given. Not sure if its related to eigen or the bundle adjuster not to happy about me using a eigen matrix.

```
Error   2   error C2039: 'epsilon' : is not a member of 'Eigen::NumTraits<ceres::Jet<T,12>>'    c:\dev\eigen-eigen-ffa86ffb5570\eigen\src\Core\IO.h 132 1   simple_bundle_adjuster
```

Comment: What error were you getting?

Comment: Is `rot` supposed to be a `Matrix` or a `Map`?  The types on left and right of copy-initialization operation (`=`) don't match.

Comment: @Ben Voigt:  FYI `Map` is an Eigen template that wraps a C-style array with the accessor functions so it can be used as a Matrix type of the template argument.  This includes being able to use it as the source of a copy assignment/constructor.

Comment: Note that it looks like the OP is trying to estimate rotation, and does so by estimating the 9 entries of a 3x3 rotation matrix. That's in general not the best idea since that problem formulation is highly overparameterized. It's much better to use a quaternion or angle-axis representation and optimise for these 3 or 4 parameters. They uniquely define a rotation, and you can easily compute a rotation matrix from that if you need one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Eigen::Map` is used to wrap a C-style array so that it can be used as an `Eigen::Matrix`.  Normally, this allows it to even write through to the underlying array.  Since you only have a `T const*`, writing is not allowed.  To remain const-correct, you need to tell Eigen the mapping to disallow writing, since you only have `T const*` pointers.  To do this, you specify that the `Map` is to a `const Matrix<...>`.

```
template <typename T>
bool operator()(const T* const camera,
    const T* const point,
    T* residuals) const {

                                                          //   vvvvv
    Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> rot = Eigen::Map < const Eigen::Matrix< T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> >(camera);
    std::cout << rot << std::endl;                            
}
```

Comment: But it gave me a new error about a missing epsilon, can i extend eigen to have this epsilon for the bundle adjuster to work

Comment: or funny, the error is only there when having   //std::cout << rot << std::endl; commented out. Will just leave the print out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need a newer version of Ceres. Checkout the version in the git repo.

The epsilon() was added in

https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/91da310aebe855e3d97f150c698221b3e4c0bce3

which is later than the 1.8.0 release.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I got it compiling and might not need a newer version. It only complains about it missing if I try to use std::cout in the cost function. Not sure why. Might take a later version when we know the 1.8 version work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is `operator()` a class member function? You can not define it outside of a class. The code below compiles

```
class MyClass{
public:
template <typename T>
bool operator()(const T* const camera,
    const T* const point,
    T* residuals) const 
    {
        Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> rot = Eigen::Map <Eigen::Matrix< T, 3, 3,     Eigen::RowMajor> >(camera);
        std::cout << rot << std::endl;
        // must return true or false, as you declare `bool` as the return type
        return true;
    }
};
```

Or, you can make the whole `MyClass` a template, and remove the `template <typename T>` from `operator()`

```
template <typename T> class MyClass{...};
```

Comment: Updated with the full code example as something else properly is going on.

Comment: Is `ceres::CostFunction` a type? If yes, add the keyword `typename` in front, as `typename ceres::CostFunction*`

Comment: I am supposed to only change the cost function, (operator() )

Comment: ye its a class, will try typename

Comment: The problem is in your `static ceres::CostFunction* Create(const double observed_x, const double observed_y)` function, if you remove it it compiles.

Comment: or I properly can as it only is a factory class, guess i do not need it

Comment: I still get the same error when i try to create a cost function without the factory.